# Azure Function App & Web API in same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a both a Web API project and a function app project which share the same services / class libraries etc. A few questions

1. Is it bad practice to place them both in the same solution (or should they be in seperate repositories
2. Should the services be registered in the Startup class of the Web Api or the function app, or a mixture of the 2? Is it okay to register services only used by the function app in the web api startup class as this would make life easier? The services will do similar things and in some cases the same services will be used by both.

I am likely to only require a few timer trigger functions, most of the application will be build on the web api.

Specifically, the rest API will serve a frontend UI and the function app will provide updates to products on timer triggers.

Thanks for any guidance in advance and apologise if these are silly questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1 - I think it's totally fine to have them both in the same (git) repository - you might be following a monorepo strategy, OR these projects might be closely related e.g. part of the same business domain/capability where you might have something like a a core Web API project (ASP.NET Core WebApi) as well as some Function App event handlers (in a Function App project) that respond to external async events and invoke the core Web API. Alternatively, if they're completely unrelated repos and you're not following a monorepo strategy then maybe they should be in separate repos.

For #2 - some services might be exclusive to the ASP.NET Core WebApi, some exclusive to the Function App, and some might be shared. Assuming all the code is in the same repo; for the shared dependencies, you might consider having a third 'class library' project in the same git repo that can be referenced by both the ASP.NET Core WebApi project as well as the Function app project. This 'class library' project could contain all the shared dependencies. Dependencies should be registered in the startup of both the Web Api AND the function app.

Comment: Ahh I see thanks Ryan, so for example a class libary called SharedServices, one called FunctionServices etc? For the ones that are shared they should be registered in both? Out of interest.. do you know what would happen if they were registered in opposite project?

Comment: you might end up with projects for "WebAPI" (ASP.NET Core WebApi project), "Functions" (Function App project), and "shared" (class library). The WebAPI and Functions project are separately hosted apps, so they'll have their own instances/configuration of shared dependencies - there would be no cross over.

Comment: This ends up resembling "Clean Architecture" or Onion Architecture. There's application logic (all the stuff the application does) which is decoupled from both the API and the Functions. That logic has its own runtime dependencies (like repositories.) The API and Functions contain minimal or less logic. They receive inputs and invoke methods in the application logic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture